# hamster: command not found and also unable to build from source code

Tags: apt, compiling, make, git-buildpackage

What is want to do is that i want to use **hamster-sidejack** tool but when i run `hamster` in terminal it is saying `hamster: command not found` and i tried

`sudo apt-get install hamster-sidejack`

but it is saying `E: Unable to locate package hamster-sidejack`

I have also tried to install this tool using katoolin.

but it is also saying `E: Unable to locate package hamster-sidejack`

so finally dicided to build it from its source

GITHUB LINK :- https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/hamster.git

after downloading the file i go to its gcc4 folder and run

`make -j2`

but its showing error

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create ../../tmp/pixie.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:16: ../../tmp/pixie.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create ../../tmp/hamster.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:16: ../../tmp/hamster.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue or is there another way to install hamster.

Please....

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Linux Mint 20.1 “Ulyssa”

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this package is [not available from APT](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=hamster-sidejack&searchon=names). According to [search on Repology](https://repology.org/project/hamster-sidejack/versions) this package has origin in Kali Linux.

To get the source and create the deb-package you can use commands below on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev build-essential debhelper-compat git

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/hamster-sidejack.git
cd hamster-sidejack

dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us # for Mint 20.1
make # for Mint 20.1

rm debian/source/format # fix error with deb-helper
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -d

sudo apt-get install ../hamster-sidejack_2.0-1kali4_amd64.deb
```

and enjoy.

Comment: still saying  `hamster: command not found`

Comment: its saying app installed but when i type hamster to run it doesn't run

Comment: LinuxMint is off-topic here. This is a just an example how Mint is different on Ubuntu. The above method works normally on normal Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Install it and retry.

Comment: See updated answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to launch hamster by navigating to *Applications* → *Sniffing & Spoofing* → *hamster*, I also got the same error message.
I solved the problem by simply launching the application from the command line with the command `hamster-sidejack`.

By the way, I noticed the same behavior if I launch ferret from *Applications* → *Sniffing & Spoofing* → *ferret*, while if I give `ferret-sidejack` in the command line, the application starts as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it not launching from applications just edit the launcher and add `-sidejack` after `hamster/ferret`, on the command line, for example:

`/use/share/kali-menu/exec-in-shell "hamster-sidejack"`